# SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, node.js

I was about to use [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) and I got this error when I followed the instructions to set up `~/.live-server.json`

```
undefined:1
var liveServer = require("live-server");
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/live-server/live-server.js:20:20)
```

Does this mean `var` cannot be contained in a JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var liveServer = require("live-server");
```

It means that you required npm module `live-server`. You don't assign json to `var liveServer`.

And when you require this module it loads and parse json file `~/.live-server.json`

Your error means that your json file isn't in correct json format - you have bug there.

Please paste your json to any json validator (for example http://jsonlint.com/)  and fix issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use var in a JSON file and you can't call any function (like require). JSON is just a format to represent data.

I just looked into the documentation very briefly but as I understand it you **can** define options in this JSON file that are then used by live-server. In this case you don't have to specify them in your js file. But in every case you have to require and start live-server inside of a JavaScript file.